# Code formatting in comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, markdown

I am supposed to use back ticks to mark code in my comments, but my iPad doesn't have a back tick on its keyboard. What should I do, buy a PC or sue Steve Jobs?  :-)

Comment: the clear answer is: *both*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the newest versions of iOS, the backtick can be accessed by holding down the apostrophe key.